# PayPal Adaptive Payments 決済状態の更新時の通知の判別

Tags: paypal

Paypal Adaptive Payments chained paymentにて第2受取人がPENDINGになったあと、
第2受取人が受取処理を行った際に通知されるIPNにtransaction_typeが存在しないため、
どの値を元にPENDINGの解消を判別すればいいかわかりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

最初のpendingのIPNとその後に受取処理を行った際に通知されるIPNには同じtxn_idが含まれるため、
そのtxn_idを利用すれば追跡できると思います。
txn_id=旧txnID & payment_status=Completed の条件を満たせば、pendingの取引が受取処理されたと判定することができると思います。

Comment: txn_idを使って判断できそうですね。
こちらで確認してみます。